# Oracle UnOptimized Read Requests

Tags: oracle, merge

It's strange that this query appears in my AWR Report as "UnOptimized". I'm hoping everyone can help me understand what is the difference in performance.

Here are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE STGE_TABLE(
   FIELD_01 NUMBER, 
   FIELD_02 NUMBER, 
   FIELD_03 DATE, 
   BATCH_ID NUMBER
) PARTITION BY RANGE (BATCH_ID) INTERVAL(1)
  PARTITION EMPTY VALUES LESS THAN (0);

CREATE TABLE LIVE_TABLE(
   FIELD_01 NUMBER, 
   FIELD_02 NUMBER, 
   FIELD_03 DATE
);
```

Here is the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_MERGE_PKG 
AS 
   PROCEDURE MERGE_MY_TWO_TABLES; 
END MY_MERGE_PKG;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_MERGE_PKG 
AS 
   PROCEDURE MERGE_MY_TWO_TABLES 
   AS 
   ln_batch_id number; 
   lc_queue_src varchar(10);
   BEGIN 
      LOOP 
      BEGIN 

         --GET THE NEXT BATCH_ID FROM THE QUEUE ALONG WITH THE lc_queue_src
         IF lc_queue_src = 'TYPE_01' THEN
            MERGE INTO LIVE_TABLE TGT
            USING (
               SELECT FIELD_01, FIELD_02, FIELD_03
               FROM STGE_TABLE
               WHERE BATCH_ID=ln_batch_id
            ) SRC
            ON (SRC.FIELD_01 = TGT.FIELD_01)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET TGT.FIELD_03 = SRC.FIELD_03
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT(TGT.FIELD_01, TGT_FIELD_03)
            VALUES(SRC.FIELD_01, SRC.FIELD_03);
         ELSE
            MERGE INTO LIVE_TABLE TGT
            USING (
               SELECT FIELD_01, FIELD_02, FIELD_03
               FROM STGE_TABLE
               WHERE BATCH_ID=ln_batch_id
            ) SRC
            ON (SRC.FIELD_01 = TGT.FIELD_01)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET TGT.FIELD_02 = SRC.FIELD_02
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT(TGT.FIELD_01, TGT_FIELD_02)
            VALUES(SRC.FIELD_01, SRC.FIELD_02);
         END IF;

      END; 
   END LOOP; 
END MERGE_MY_TWO_TABLES;
```

In the AWR Report it shows that the merge in the ELSE block in not optimized. I'm not quite understanding why if they are virtually the identical merge statement.

Any help in the matter is greatly appreciated.